# Spring Batch: Set entity within an entity

Tags: spring-batch

I have an entity **User** which has another entity as Department.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer salary;

    @ManyToOne
    private Department department;
}
```

And another entity department

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Department {

    public Department(String departmentName){
        this.name = departmentName;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;
}
```

**Processor** class

```
@Component
public class Processor implements ItemProcessor<User, User> {

    @Override
    public User process(User item) throws Exception {
        return item;
    }
}
```

**Writer** class

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class DBWriter implements ItemWriter<User> {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public DBWriter(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends User> users) throws Exception {
        log.info("Inserting value of user with data size: {}", users.size());
        userRepository.saveAll(users);
    }
}
```

And my **SpringBatchConfig** class

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchConfig {


    private final DepartmentRepository departmentRepository;

    public SpringBatchConfig(DepartmentRepository departmentRepository) {
        this.departmentRepository = departmentRepository;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,
                   StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                   ItemReader<User> reader,
                   ItemProcessor<User, User> process,
                   ItemWriter<User> writer
    ) {
        Step step = stepBuilderFactory.get("user-insertion")
                .<User, User>chunk(100000)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(process)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("user-insertion")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<User> itemReader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<User> flatFileItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        flatFileItemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource("src/main/resources/users.csv"));
        flatFileItemReader.setName("CSV-Reader");
        flatFileItemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
        flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(getLineMapper());
        Department department = departmentRepository.save(new Department("Development"));
        return flatFileItemReader;
    }

    @Bean
    public LineMapper<User> getLineMapper() {
        DefaultLineMapper<User> defaultLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();

        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(",");
        lineTokenizer.setStrict(false);
        lineTokenizer.setNames("name", "department", "salary");

        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<User> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(User.class);

        defaultLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        defaultLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);

        return defaultLineMapper;
    }
}
```

I am not able to assign the department to the users at the time of batch insert. Let's assume that a single department can be assigned to a current list of users.

**How am I able to insert the department in user?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a write operation in the reader's bean definition method:

```
Department department = departmentRepository.save(new Department("Development"));
```

This is not correct. It is not expected to write such code in a Spring bean definition method.

What you need to do is make your reader read `User` instances and set the department on each instance. Then your writer would save both the user and its department. `UserRepository` should already do that if your JPA mapping is correct.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. I just didn't want to loop through millions of records. Anyway thanks. I think I will implement the way you told me to.